# Using wait() function in Android App

Tags: android, loops, wait

I am trying to simulate changing GPS location by simulating it. I am trying to change gps variable manually every second. I have tried various methods, but neither of them looks to work for me. Maybe someone will spot an error in my code? Most of the time screen just goes blank and activity doesn't even load.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

/**
 * Created by Larry on 18/12/2015.
 */
public class travel extends AppCompatActivity {
    float gps = 0;

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.travel_layout2);
        String[] words = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.information);
        String[] left = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.left);
        String[] right = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.right);
        String[] bubble = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bubble);
        Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.beginning);
        Global app = Global.getInstance();
        String beginning=app.getValue(0);
        String ending=app.getValue(1);
        int begin = 1;
        int end = 1;
        int resId;
        int y=0;
        float latBegin=0;
        float latEnd=0;
        float lonBegin=0;
        float lonEnd=0;
        String name;
        TextView test;
        ImageView image;
        RelativeLayout layout;


        // deleted some code which initializes the page

        gps = latBegin;
        while (gps < latEnd) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            gps = gps + 0.001f;
            //Handler h = new Handler();

            // h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            //   @Override
            //   public void run() {
            // DO DELAYED STUFF
            //}, 1000);


            //SystemClock.sleep(1000);




            // Thread.sleep(1000);


            // Handler handler = new Handler();
            //handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            //public void run() { }, 500);
            //});
            //setTimeout(onCreate(){ },1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see blank screen because you are doing time consuming operations on UI thread. You can use something like this to execute piece of code periodically, instead of `while` loop:

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //modify value
            //do something with new value
            handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
        }
    }, 500);
```

Comment: it doesn't look to change. This time I really don't understand what I am doing wrong. By "update UI", do you mean onCreate method?

Comment: You need to put all code below `gps = latBegin;` inside `run()` method. By update UI I meant using modified value anyhow. It doesn't need to be related with UI at all. I've updated an answer.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZ9NgFYEMxp4KSJPUyaQCj7x--NQ6kvcX This playlist discusses in detail concurrency in Java and Android, you can start at 29 if you want lots of background info for Android concurrency frameworks, or just 33 and 34 if you just want to know about posting runnables,

Comment: Looks like those will be very good lessons. Thanks! I will check them in a bit. It is very sad that Android wat() is not as simple as in C language though